# Dans quels termes « jouit-on » en français?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Autrement dit, quelles sont les nuances de la différence sémantique entre *jouir*, *se délecter de quelque chose*, *prendre son plaisir*,  *se faire régaler* et *s'en donner*?

*Jouit-on* seulement au sens d'un coït?

Peut-on *se faire régaler* avec une idée,  ou seulement avec des soupes?

Dit-on qu'on *a pris du plaisir à faire quelque chose* plus souvent qu'on *a pris plaisir à quelque chose*? Peut-on dire « prendre plaisir  à faire quelque chose », c'est-à-dire, sans l'article ou d'autres mots auxiliaires?

Et *s'en donner*, est-ce que c'est une expression souvent utilisée, ou est-ce qu'elle n'est acceptable que dans un contexte limité?

Answer (score 4):

De manière générale, ces termes s'emploient pour un plaisir physique autant que pour un plaisir moral et les nuances de sens ne sont pas clairement marquées.

En particulier :

- **[*jouir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouir)** signifie avant tout « ressentir du plaisir », « profiter » et dans un second sens, en particulier en langage légal ou très soutenu « bénéficier »¹. Le sens le plus courant hors du domaine légal se rapporte au plaisir sexuel mais ça n'a rien d'une obligation et on peut tout à fait « jouir du beau temps » ou « jouir de la compagnie de sa famille ».
- **[*Se délecter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9lecter)** est d'après le TLFi synonyme de *jouir*. En ce qui me concerne, il évoque surtout la nourriture et n'a le sens de *jouir* que par analogie.
- ***Prendre son plaisir*** est légèrement différent en ce que *son* implique à mon sens qu'il ne s'agit que de *son* plaisir et pas de celui des autres, je le comprends donc comme « prendre du plaisir au dépends d'autrui ». En revance, ***prendre plaisir*** et ***prendre du plaisir*** ont le même sens que *jouir* et le premier est certainement le terme le plus courant pour décrire cette situation.
- Inversement, [***se faire régaler***](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9galer) implique que le plaisir est causé par un agent, et non pas par une situation, on ne se fait pas régaler par une promenade, mais on peut se faire régaler par ses amis. Ceci ne concerne pas ***se régaler***, qui est synonyme de *se délecter*.
- ***[S'en donner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner)*** implique qu'on profite entièrement de la chose, on peut *jouir* partiellement d'une situation, mais si on s'en donne c'est qu'il n'y a aucun obstacle au plaisir.

---

¹ « La Provence *jouit* d'un climat méditerranéen » par exemple.

Comment: Pour « prendre (du) plaisir », pourquoi détourner l’interrogation sur « prendre son plaisir » sans parler des autres possibilités ? Aussi, je ne crois pas que « s'en donner » puisse être compris sans complément.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez [« En voilà une vraie noce! Ah! bien, **ils s'en donnent** !... Dis-donc, Putois, tu les entends! (Zola, Le Bouton de rose,1878, I, 1, p. 223) »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner).

Comment: Certainement le terme le plus courant, je ne [crois pas](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendre+plaisir%2C+prendre+du+plaisir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19). Réponse au dernier commentaire: Ok avec une phrase d'introduction, deux interjections et un point d'exclamation, ça passe ! (au 19e siècle en tout cas…)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez me suis planté en l'écrivant. Et sinon *on s'en donne* je l'emploie de temps en temps.

Answer (score 3):

**Jouir :**

En plus du coït, le verbe *jouir* peut être utilisé dans l'expression juridique "jouir de ses droits", mais rien d'autre ! Ce serait techniquement acceptable de l'utiliser pour le reste, mais dans la pratique, mieux vaut éviter.

**Se régaler :**

On peut se régaler (attention, pas "se faire régaler" !) pour des soupes mais aussi pour des événements ("Je suis allée au parc d'attractions, je me suis régalée !"). Quand on l'utilise pour des événements, c'est plutôt pour dire que l'on s'est amusé. On ne l'emploierait pas vraiment pour dire "J'ai vu un ami, je me suis régalé !".

**Prendre (du) plaisir :**

Il est plus commun de dire *prendre plaisir à* que *prendre du plaisir à.* J'ai du mal à savoir si la seconde est acceptable ou non, je conseille de toujours utiliser la première.

Pour la différence entre *prendre plaisir à faire quelque chose* ou *prendre plaisir à quelque chose*, ça ne dépend que de s'il y a un verbe. On dira : "prendre plaisir à le voir", "prendre plaisir à aller au cinéma", mais "prendre plaisir à faire un gâteau" et pas "prendre plaisir à un gâteau". **On prend toujours plaisir à faire une action**, on ne prend jamais plaisir à un objet.

**S'en donner :**

L'expression "s'en donner" n'existe pas telle quelle, il s'agit en fait de "s'en donner à cœur joie". On ne l'utilise pas vraiment au quotidien, mais elle fonctionne dans tous les cas.

**Conclusion :**

Ces expressions ne sont pas très utilisées au quotidien. Malheureusement, on utilisera plutôt un banal "J'ai beaucoup aimé", "j'ai adoré",...

Comment: *Se faire régaler* est tout à fait correct, il s'agit du passif de *régaler (quelqu'un)* qui signifie « faire plaisir à (quelqu'un) ». Et *jouir* s'emploie sans problème en langage soutenu pour *posséder*.

Comment: @Evpok: Connaître « *se faire régaler* » est quand même beaucoup moins utile que connaître « *se régaler* »… Pour *jouir* je suis d'accord, mais une fois de plus, *posséder* c'est pas la meilleure approximation ;-) Sans ce détail, qui mériterait une petite révision, c'est ma foi une très bonne réponse.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La question portait (entre autres) explicitement sur *se faire régaler*.

Comment: @Evpok : La question portait sur "se délecter", "jouir", etc., je pense que Manjusri voulait dire "régaler". D'ailleurs, l'exemple utilisé concernait la soupe. J'aurais en effet dû parler de "se faire régaler" en plus, mais je trouve le -1 sévère !
Je suis d'accord pour la remarque sur *jouir*.

Comment: Le -1 était pour le « mais rien d'autre ! ».

Comment: On peut également jouir d'une excellente santé, ou de toutes ses facultés, et une société peut jouir d'une bonne réputation par exemple, sans qu'il y ait la moindre équivoque.